# Is it always possible to interchange the partial derivative and the summation sign

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I was wondering if it is always possible to interchange the summation sign and the partial derivative. I think it is since I cannot come up with a counter example. Can anyone please confirm this?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\sum_{i=1}^k a \cdot x^2)=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (a \cdot x^2)$

Comment: If you know that the partial derivatives of the summands exist. Something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(|x|+ (-|x|))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|x|+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-|x|)$ would have the right hand side not well defined at $x=0$, even though the left is well defined and equal to $0$.

Comment: Note that if the sum has an infinite number of terms you can also run into trouble.

Comment: Thank you for these insightful examples